# Forbidden response in large url

Tags: php, apache, http, apache2, centos

I need to generate a large url like this:

`/backend.php/Inscription/export/1577,1578,1579,..., 1580 etc....`

But when the URL has more than 400 IDs, I obtain the following error:

`You don't have permission to access /backend.php/Inscription/export/1577..... on this server.`

Is there a problem with my configuration on the server?

Comment: See [related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/417142/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-url-in-different-browsers?rq=1) - consider using POST if you can.

Comment: Does your script work (or the error message change) if you post to a shorter URL?